# How can you get the version number of your Room Database?

Tags: android, android-room

I have some code that I would only like to run when I know for certain that the Room migrations I have have completed.  Is there a way to find out which version number my Room instance is on?  I have the latest code:

```
@Database(entities = [AnalyticsEvent::class, ListenItem::class, LastPositionHeard::class, 
DownloadItem::class], version = 3) //I would like to retrieve this information
@TypeConverters(RoomTypeConverters::class)
abstract class MyRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

  abstract fun analyticsEventsDao(): AnalyticsEventsDao

  abstract fun listeningStatsDao(): ListeningStatsDao

  abstract fun lastPositionHeardDao(): LastPositionHeardDao

  abstract fun downloadsDao(): DownloadsDao

  companion object {
    // Singleton prevents multiple instances of database opening at the
    // same time.
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: MyRoomDatabase? = null

    val MIGRATION_1_TO_2 = Migration1To2()
    val MIGRATION_2_TO_3 = Migration2To3()
    const val LUMINARY_DATABASE_NAME = "room_database"

    fun getDatabase(context: Context): MyRoomDatabase {
      val tempInstance = INSTANCE
      if (tempInstance != null) {
        return tempInstance
      }
      synchronized(this) {
        val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
          context.applicationContext,
          LuminaryRoomDatabase::class.java,
          LUMINARY_DATABASE_NAME
        ).addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_TO_2, MIGRATION_2_TO_3)
        .build()
    INSTANCE = instance
    return instance
   }
  }
 }
}
```

But what I would like to do is something like this:

```
val instanceVersionNumber = MyRoomDatabase.getDatabase().versionNumber
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You are assuming that the schema version number is only updated after the migrations have completed, or that the entire migrations + version update are in a single transaction. I don't think that is a safe assumption. If nothing else, it's an internal Room implementation detail that ideally we would not rely upon.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, that's what I was afraid of.

Comment: @CommonsWare is there a way to tell when the migrations have been completed?

Comment: AFAIK, by the time `build()` returns the database, they have been completed.

Comment: @CommonsWare  Actually, that's not true, after stepping through the debugger.  The migrations are performed in a background thread by the looks of it that completes sometime later.

Comment: If so, that's seriously bad. [This issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143647723) mentions that each of your migration callbacks gets called, so that's a possible workaround hook. But I'll need to look into this further, hopefully this weekend.

Comment: I can't reproduce your threading findings. I was wrong in thinking that the migrations were run before `build()` returned. Instead, they seem to be run lazily on the first database access. However, at least for a synchronous DAO function (i.e., one not using `LiveData` or another reactive return type), it seems like the migration work is being done on the current thread. So, if nothing else, you could add some do-nothing synchronous DAO function and call that after you `build()` the database, so you control when the migrations get run.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the research.  I'll try your approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an extension function in Kotlin to grab the version number.  The key is to call `openHelper` from your Room database which returns a `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper` object where you can then get to the actual DB attributes.

```
fun Context.getDBVersion() = RoomDatabase.getDatabase(this)?.openHelper?.readableDatabase?.version.toString()
```

Comment: At the moment, it seems that `openHelper` isn't reachable in Room `2.5.0-alpha02`

Comment: Yes, it's no more working in latest version of ROOM.

Comment: It may have gone away 2.5.0-alpha02, but is back in `androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0-beta02`

Answer (score 0):

Update to Sneg's comment for Room 2.5.0

```
fun RoomDatabase.getDBVersion(): Int {
    return this.openHelper.readableDatabase.version
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this is different from [Sneg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64137623/3169238)